# Should we combine topically-similar tags?

Tags: discussion

We now have two questions tagged [Class Bravo](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-bravo) and none tagged [Airspace](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airspace), which to me would be the logical parent tag for any airspace questions. Should various classes have their own tags? Should they be synonyms for a master Airspace tag?

How should we think about this?

Comment: Generally, a more specific tag is preferred if it can maintain a number of questions.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information (i.e. questions) yet to see if a class B tag makes sense. Personally I would go for "airspace" because I doubt that class B airspace has enough unique issues to warrant its own tag but that's just my opinion. The two questions right now are about 'busting' and operating in class B, but you could replace B with C and the questions would still be valid. they're really about controlled, busy airspace, not about class B per se.

Comment: Just an administrative note: Tag synonyms were ***not*** designed to group a bunch of related subjects into a type of super class. Tag synonyms should only be used when folks will commonly use two completely different words to mean the exact same thing. Think: "cars" vs. "autos".

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: I'd edit if I could, but the "Class Bravo" tag has been changed to "Class B".  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think that we should remove the various tags for the specific types of airspace and replace them all with one [airspace](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airspace) tag.

There **are** issues and questions specific to each class of airspace, however I highly doubt that someone would follow and answer questions only tagged to a specific class because we need to know about all classes of airspace and their operating rules in order to operate in them.  I don't know of anybody who considers themselves an expert on Class A airspace rules, but not Class D, etc.

The same people will be answering airspace questions regardless of the class of airspace.

Comment: I like this. I'd add that I think it makes more sense to combine tags (airspace + faa) than it would to create a conjoined tag.

Comment: @egid: That's a good point, I'll remove the last sentence since I agree with you!

Answer (score 2):

I tend to disagree with simply using a monolithic [airspace](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airspace) tag. I think using that tag would be appropriate when a question encompasses multiple types of airspace, but many questions are going to be asking specifically about one, and it seems appropriate to tag them as such. Blanket tags which cover tons of questions are the less useful as a search filter.

We should remember there are more types of airspace than just the *classes*. There's also MOA's, warning, restricted, prohibited, temporary restrictions, ADIZ, TRSA, voluntary restrictions like wildlife refuges and nuclear power plants, and more. All of those technically would fit under *airspace*, but it wouldn't be very useful.

Even if [airspace](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airspace) was limited to implying airspace *Classes A-G*, I also disagree that people would be equally likely to be experts in each of the airspace classes. A pilot here in the Northeastern US might have a lot of advice for navigating through and around Class B, whereas a pilot in Alaska might have a lot of practical knowledge about operating in uncontrolled Class G. Imagine you've never flown through a Class B, and you want to do a search for all questions tagged [class-b](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-b) before your trip to see if any questions stand out, which you hadn't considered before.

If nothing else, since operating rules in the various airspaces are different, I feel they warrant unique tags.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and when I was considering the question this was my first thought as well.  However, the operating rules for each of the different classes of airspace are very similar with a very short list of differences.  Remember, that someone could also search for "Class B" in questions tagged "airspace" if they wanted to.  It doesn't have to have it's own tag for searching.